# Does 4D-PAM5 has DC component?

Tags: modulation

Because of redundancy( 4^5>2^8 ) 4D-PAM5 has, I think there is no DC component and synchronization problem but I can't sure.

What is the truth?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's an extensive synchronization problem – how would a modulation solve that? Your receiver still has to figure out symbol timing of the transmitter.

And: on **average**, yes, there *should* be no DC component, but for short observation times, of course there is a DC component in pulse amplitude modulations.

This is the same [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34904/13320) you got for your [NRZ Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/why-nrz-l-and-nrz-i-line-coding-have-dc-component). Why should this change?

I think your question is an indication of you missing a solid understanding of the *stochastic process' properties* and the *properties of a time-limited observation*. If the term *stochastic process* doesn't ring a bell: you should read up on that, it will make further studies much, much more easy for you!

Comment: Thanks. But what I was supposed to say is "Is there DC component can cause 'base wandering' with 4d-PAM5 shceme and problem of 'synchronization of bitfield' ". I think NRZ surely has, so I didn't  add aditory comment.

Comment: and sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: your English is very fine! Don't worry. But add that info to your question itself, not as a comment to an answer. You should also clarify what exactly you mean with "base wandering" and "synchronization of bitfield"; I think these terms aren't 100% clear.

Comment: Thanks! 

Here is the term "base wandering" in my text book. 
"A long string of 0s or 1s can cause a drift in the baseline (baseline wandering) and make it difficult for the receiver to decode correctly."

Here is the term "synchronization" which I want to talk about.
"To correctly interpret the signals received from the sender, the receiver’s bit intervals must correspond exactly to the sender’s bit intervals."

Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Why can't I insert new line in my comment? :(

Comment: You *must*add that info to your question, not as a comment